# How to flatten JSON data in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have Source from SQL DB where data stored as JSON. Please see below image where record column has contains JSON.

[image]

The record column contains JSON Data like below. I am trying to flatten the JSON column so that each item inside the JSON suppose to be in tabular form. Is it possible to do this in Azure Data Factory?

```
{
   "resourceType":"Encounter",
   "id":"9i5W6tp-JTd-24252",
   "meta":{
      "versionId":"1591978948308",
      "lastUpdated":"2020-06-12T16:22:28.308Z"
   },
   "status":"finished",
   "class":{
      "system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-ActCode",
      "code":"AMB"
   },
   "type":[
      {
         "coding":[
            {
               "system":"http://snomed.info/sct",
               "code":"185345009",
               "display":"Encounter for symptom"
            }
         ],
         "text":"Encounter for symptom"
      }
   ],
   "subject":{
      "reference":"Patient/9i5W6tp-JTd-24249",
      "display":"Mrs. tonia30 back373"
   },
   "participant":[
      {
         "individual":{
            "reference":"Practitioner/9i5W6tp-JTd-24251",
            "display":"Dr. Stevie682"
         }
      }
   ],
   "period":{
      "start":"1962-05-27T08:26:51Z",
      "end":"1962-06-10T08:26:51Z"
   },
   "reasonCode":[
      {
         "coding":[
            {
               "system":"http://snomed.info/sct",
               "code":"232353008",
               "display":"Perennial allergic rhinitis with seasonal variation"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "serviceProvider":{
      "reference":"Organization/9i5W6tp-JTd-24250",
      "display":"HOSPITAL"
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to fully expand the json object or only expand the first layer like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PkIh.png)?

Comment: You can't flatten a JSON doc embedded inside a column in ADF data flows today. However, if you can export that column contents to a .json file, you can then read it in as a JSON source and flatten the arrays. This is a commonly requested feature that we're working on so you can take a JSON column and transform it without needing the extra step, which we are actively working on.

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT Thanks Mark for the suggestion. That may be the solution by storing the data as a .JSON then use ADF

Comment: @JosephXu The end goal is to fully expand the JSON content. Thank you!

Comment: HI @DineshMadhup, Merry Christmas in advance!  Hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm agree with @Mark Kromer. We can not flatten a JSON doc embedded inside a column in ADF data flows today. It's impossible for now.

Suggestions:

1. Copy the SQL table data to the sink as the JSON format file.
2. Then use the exported JSON format file as source and flatten the JSON array to get the tabular form.

That's the workaround for the issue. We hope Data Factory product team can make progress and update us soon. Waiting for the good news and thanks Mark again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using ADF data flows can flatten JSON.

Comment: Looks like good news then. Can you share?